# SQL query to retrieve XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have some XML in SQL Server:

[image]

Code to retrieve:

```
declare @xmlresponse xml

select top 1 @xmlrespone = xmlresponse from dto.t

;with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www3')
select inputRefId = Node.Data.Value('.', 'varchar(50)')
from @xmlresponse.nodes('.') Node(Data)
```

This returns both fields (`inputrefid` and `crn`) as one string.

I would like to retrieve the values in separate fields starting with the inputrefid, but no matter what I try I get NULL.

e.g

```
select inputRefId = Node.Data.Value('(/inputRefId)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with this XQuery:

```
;WITH xmlnamespaces('http://www3' AS ns)
SELECT
    inputRefId = Data.value('(ns:inputRefId)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    crn = Data.value('(ns:crn)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @xmlresponse.nodes('/resultDTO') Node(Data)
```

The point is that your top-level node - `<resultDTO>` does *not* have the `http://www3` XML namespace - so you cannot really use the `http://www3` as the *default* XML namespace for all the nodes in the XML - you need to be more specific and only apply it where it's really been set.